# Replace text in files in current directory without dired

Tags: replace, emacs

How to replace a particular text in all files in the **current directory** (dir of current buffer/file) without using **dired**. Also is there a way to preview the matches as well before replacing (to be safe).

I use **helm-do-ag** to search in current directory and it has search as you type behaviour

Comment: I’m not sure I’ve understood how you want to perform the replacement, but does the edit mode work for you? (Press C-c C-e with a list of results.)

Comment: I have come quite fond of using a combination of `grep` and `wgrep`:  https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep

Comment: Is there something simple like those in notepad++ or sublime text. Few of the time it is preferred to use simpler ones

Comment: Not clear to me what you want to do. What do you mean by "replace text in files"?

Comment: @Drew question edited

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `dired`?

Comment: while visiting a file, it should ask for a search string and replacement string and on RET, all the files should be replaced. I prefer not to use dired everytime for the same